# Where and Group By Using Moongose API MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have written an aggregation function which will count the Message. Based on Message Status.

```
exports.countRecords = function(req, res) {    
Message.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$message_status",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: 1
    }
}], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.jsonp(result);
});
};
```

Now i need to add a condition to count only when the channel_message_ID and channel_thread_Id are equal so i have modified the logic like below:

```
Message.aggregate([{
   $match: {
        channel_message_ID: { $eq: ["$channel_message_ID", "$channel_thread_Id"]}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$message_status",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    },

}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: 1
    }
}], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.jsonp(result);
});
```

};

It is not at all working. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below solution:

**$project:**

```
Message.aggregate([{
{"$project": {
      "channel_message_ID":1,
      "channel_thread_Id":1,
      "message_status": 1,
      "cond": {"$eq":["$channel_message_ID","$channel_thread_Id"]}
    }
  },
  {"$match":{"cond": true}},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$message_status",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    },

}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: 1
    }
}], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.jsonp(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a new field to the document at the first stage of the aggregation pipeline, this can be done by using the [$addFields]
(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage

```
{ "$addFields" : { "idMatch" : { "$eq" : [ "$channel_message_ID" , "$channel_thread_Id" ] } } }
```

This will create us a new field on the documents flowing through the pipeline telling us if there is a match on the 2 fields. We can then push this in to a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage

```
{ $match: { "idMatch" : true } }
```

Then you can run the rest of the $group:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$message_status", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
```

then sort stage:

```
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 } }
```

So for example if we add the following documents to a mongodb collection:

```
db.test.insertMany([{
    message_status: "In Progress",
    channel_thread_Id: "A",
    channel_message_ID: "A"
},
{
    message_status: "Completed",
    channel_thread_Id: "A",
    channel_message_ID: "A"
},
{
    message_status: "In Progress",
    channel_thread_Id: "A",
    channel_message_ID: "B"
},
{
    message_status: "Completed",
    channel_thread_Id: "A",
    channel_message_ID: "B"
}]);


{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("599abef4f0cd60f52d67215a"),
                ObjectId("599abef4f0cd60f52d67215b"),
                ObjectId("599abef4f0cd60f52d67215c"),
                ObjectId("599abef4f0cd60f52d67215d")
        ]
}
```

We can then run the following aggregation query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
   { "$addFields" : { "idMatch" : { "$eq" : [ "$channel_message_ID" , "$channel_thread_Id" ] } } },
   { $match: { "idMatch" : true } },
   { "$group" : { "_id" : "$message_status", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
   { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 } }
]);
```

Which will return the expected results of

```
{ "_id" : "Completed", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "In Progress", "count" : 1 }
```